# How to display a byte array image from model when its null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to leave as null or show as an image if that byte array image existing in DB column.

Currently I'm showing its like this

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfilePicture)" width="80" height="80" />
```

but when this `Model.ProfilePicture` null I'm getting error like following

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inArray

Comment: Just enclose it in `if (Model.ProfilePicture != null) { <img ... /> }`

Comment: What do you want to show when Model.ProfilePicture is null?

Comment: @StephenMuecke why dont you post as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `<img>` tag in a `if` block that check if the property has a value

```
@if (Model.ProfilePicture != null)
{
    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfilePicture)" width="80" height="80" />
}
```